# How to disable shortcut N+Return for opening Notes

Tags: notes.app

On macOS Ventura 13.0.1, default Notes are opened with <kbd>N</kbd>+<kbd>Return</kbd>. When I work with gdb, I use <kbd>N</kbd>+<kbd>Return</kbd> every time, but Notes opens in a new window.

How do I disable this obnoxious feature?

Comment: There must be other keys involved N+return does noting for me and never has

Comment: I can second that, n+return does nothing for me too. Review your shortcuts in Settings > Keyboard > Keyboard Shortcuts